# reading value of button text using beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Trying to read button value **Amazing Picture** but I am getting noting using below code I wrote.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = '<button type="button" class="json-toggle">Amazing Picture</button>'


def match_class(target):
    target = target.split()
    def do_match(tag):
        try:
            classes = dict(tag.attrs)["class"]
        except KeyError:
            classes = ""
        # print classes
        # classes = classes.split()
        return all(c in classes for c in target)
    return do_match



soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

matches = soup.findAll(match_class("json-toggle"))
for m in matches:
    print m
    print "-"*10

matches = soup.findAll(match_class("json-toggle"))
for m in matches:
    print m
    print "-"*10
```

Comment: `print(soup.select_one('button.json-toggle').text)` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely that throws error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup do you use? I'm using `beautifulsoup4==4.9.0`

Comment: alot behind 4.1, its at my workplace so I cannot upgrade myself

Comment: 4.1 is *ancient*, I recommend to upgrade. You can do `soup.findAll(class_='json-toggle')`, but I don't have that version of bs4 to test it.

Comment: Try get `.get_text()` or `.getText()` Or `.string`